# Multiclass classification - Optimizing for recall in subset of classes

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, python

As part of a wider analysis, I'm seeking a method to reliably recall the outer margins (~10% each) of a data set. I don't mind if precision is lower as a result.

I've separated the data into 3 ordinal classes, and am looking for a method to maximize the recall of the top and bottom classes (The middle can be shrunk as much as needed). Are there any classification algorithms that accommodate this?

I'm new to the data science scene, so it's likely I'm just searching using the wrong keywords, but nothing is coming up for me. Paper solutions are fine, but if anyone knows of a related Python (or R) library that would be ideal.

Comment: If you really don't care about the middle class and care only about recall for the outer two classes, the optimal thing to do is probably to *never* predict the middle, and basically make a binary classifier between the outer two. Since this probably isn't what you want, you should think about what you actually do want. As @JimBoy notes, this might be anomaly detection, or it might be as you described but with a lesser weight on recall for the middle class, or...something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As part of a wider analysis, I'm seeking a method to reliably recall the outer margins (~10% each) of a data set. I don't mind if precision is lower as a result.

First, you should read up on the *no free lunch theorem*. Max Kuhn explains it very well in his presentations. This will give you some hints on how to pick an algorithm.

Second, you might think about re-framing you problem to *anomaly detection*.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is very similar to a [Linear Support Vector Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Linear_SVM).
As already stated, you should make a binary classifier between the outer classes. Linear SVM, Logistic regression, or Linear Perceptron are some of your options here.

[Here](http://pythonprogramming.net/linear-svc-example-scikit-learn-svm-python/) is a good example of Linear SVM with Python's scikit-learn module and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/vignettes/svmdoc.pdf) is the documentation of R's libsvm.